# How Programmatically tap the Wp8 screen

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, gesture-recognition

In my app i am working with tap events, by taping on my WP screen im displaying the X,Y Coordinates in Text-block. **now trying to tap Programmatically on Screen with passing X,Y Coordinates.** 
How can i do that .

Hear is my code to get X,Y Values

```
 private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, 
        Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
          Point tapLocation = e.GetPosition(viewfinderCanvas);
        if (tapLocation != null)
        {
          focusBracket.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,
        tapLocation.X);
          focusBracket.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 
        tapLocation.Y);
          double tapX = tapLocation.X;
          double tapY = tapLocation.Y;
          focusBracket.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
          this.txtDebug.Text = string.Format("Tapping Coordinates are X={0:N2}, Y={1:N2}", tapX, tapY);
        });
        }
        }
        catch (Exception error){
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
          txtDebug.Text = error.Message;

        }); }}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You want to tap on what and why? Why not directly call the tap event handler instead?

Comment: i want to tap on screen Programmatic , passing X,Y Coordinates through code.

Comment: You can't programmatically tap anything unless you program a robot.